# Is it compulsory to get a code sign certificate from a CA like Digicert, if I am going to publich my app on Microsoft Store?

Tags: code-signing, windows-store, code-signing-certificate

I am an undergraduate and new here. I have developed a MP3 music player app (.NET c#) like Groove music.

I want to know that --- **Is it compulsory to get a code sign certificate for my source code from a CA like Digicert, if I am going to publish my app on Microsoft Store?**

But they're very expensive. Isn't that?

Thanks.